# Why do I sometimes have to double escape spaces in rsync paths?

Tags: ssh, rsync, path, syntax

When referring to paths with spaces, e.g. `Steve Jobs`, I can either backslash escape, or surround with quotes, when the path is the local directory:

```
rsync Steve\ Jobs user@remote:/
```

or

```
rsync "Steve Jobs" user@remote:/
```

However, when `Steve Jobs` is the remote directory, surrounding with quotes is not sufficient. I *also* have to backslash escape the space:

```
rsync user@remote:/"Steve\ Jobs" .
```

Anyone know why this oddity happens?

If this is an artifact of SSH, why does SSH present this oddity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`rsync`** is passing the string within quotes to the remote machine.  If you escape a space in quotes, then that backslash becomes part of the string (it is not eaten by your shell).

The [`rsync` manual page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/rsync) refers to escaping:

> If you need to transfer a filename that contains whitespace, you can either specify the **`--protect-args`** (**`-s`**) option, or you'll need to escape the whitespace in a way that the remote shell will understand. For instance:
>
> `CWrsync -av host:'file\ name\ with\ spaces' /dest`

You can see how special characters are (or are not) eaten by the shell using a simple script like this:

```
#!/bin/sh
n=1
echo "$@"
for i in "$@"
do
    echo "$n:$i"
    n=`expr $n + 1`
done
```

calling that `args`:

```
$ args "xx\ yy"; args "xx yy"
xx\ yy
1:xx\ yy
xx yy
1:xx yy
```

Since `rsync` does not add quotes (unless asked, using `-s`), the spaces have to be handled specially when sent in as part of a shell command to the other machine.