# rsync syntax error on round braces

Tags: linux, bash, rsync

I have this problem with rsync. If I run this command

`rsync -rltD --delete --update --itemize-changes /data/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/ michele-backup@192.168.1.26:/backup-michele/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/`

I get this error.

```
bash: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: -c: line 0: `rsync --server -ulDtre.iLsfxC --log-format=%i --delete . /backup-michele/Program Files (x86)/'
rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (0 bytes received so far) [sender]
rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at io.c(235) [sender=3.1.3]
```

The paths have been corrected.
Do you know how to solve it?

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [Why do I sometimes have to double escape spaces in rsync paths?](https://superuser.com/q/994693/432690) Try with `michele-backup@192.168.1.26:'/backup-michele/Program\ Files\ \(x86\)/'` where single-quotes are for the local shell and backslashes are for the remote shell; xor `--protect-args`. Please respond by commenting and tell me if this works.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski your first solution work. If you add it as an answer I will mark it as solution